# Convergence of two equal infinite series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have to infinite sums $\sum_{n \geq0}a_n$ and $\sum_{n \geq0}b_n.$ such that  $\sum_{n \geq0}a_n$ =  $\sum_{n \geq0}b_n.$ Suppose that $\sum_{n \geq0}a_n$ converges to $L.$ How would I explicitly prove that $\sum_{n \geq0}b_n$ also converges to $L?$ Since $\sum_{n \geq0}a_n$ converges to $L$ I have that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $N \geq0$ such that if $k \geq N$ we have $|\sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n-L| < \epsilon.$ Then $|\sum_{n = 0}^{k}b_n-L| = |\sum_{n = 0}^{k}b_n-\sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n+ \sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n-L| \leq |\sum_{n = 0}^{k}b_n-\sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n|+ |\sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n-L| < \epsilon+|\sum_{n = 0}^{k}b_n-\sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n|.$

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You need to clarify what the equality symbol means here, and also the notation $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n$

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly we know
$$
\sum_{n \geq0}a_n =  \sum_{n \geq0}b_n.
\tag1$$
I would say **by definition** (1) means:
$$
\text{the series }\sum_{n \geq0}a_n\text{ and }\sum_{n \geq0}b_n \text{ both converge to the same finite value }L.
\tag2$$
In some conttxts, $(1)$ could also allow
$$
\text{the series }\sum_{n \geq0}a_n\text{ and }\sum_{n \geq0}b_n \text{ both diverge to }+\infty
\tag3$$
or
$$
\text{the series }\sum_{n \geq0}a_n\text{ and }\sum_{n \geq0}b_n \text{ both diverge to }-\infty
\tag4$$
Please do not write $(1)$ in case both series diverge [except in the special cases $(3)$ or $(4)$].

Answer (score 0):

You have the exact right idea, but you forget that given that a sequence converges, you can make it smaller than "any $\varepsilon$" - in this case you can make it smaller than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.
**Here is my solution:** Let $\varepsilon > 0$, the goal is now to find some $N \ge 0$ such that
$$k \ge N \Rightarrow |\sum_{n = 1}^k b_n - L| < \varepsilon.$$
Assuming that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^k b_n = \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^k a_n$, we can pick some $N_1$ such that
$$k \ge N_1 \Rightarrow |\sum_{n = 1}^k b_n - \sum_{n=1}^k a_n| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Furthermore, we can pick $N_2$ such that
$$k \ge N_2 \Rightarrow |\sum_{n = 1}^k a_n - L| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Setting $N = \max(N_1, N_2)$ (which ensures that $k\ge N$  implies both inequalities), we can use the same steps to conclude that if $k \ge N$ we must have that
$$
|\sum_{n = 0}^{k}b_n-L|  \leq |\sum_{n = 0}^{k}b_n-\sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n|+ |\sum_{n = 0}^{k}a_n-L| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon,
$$
which was to be shown.
Hope this helps!